# ContentType for image in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, mime-types

I used

```
contentType.equalsIgnoreCase("image/png");
```

for receiving `png` images. But i need to get any images of all formats. so how to declare `contentType` for all format

Comment: you can try "image/*"

Answer (score 0):

You can try using **"image/*"** whcih will accept all types of image.

read the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html#PendingIntent)

Comment: please expand question. what you want to do actually. from where you are receiving images ?

Comment: this is chat application where we post and receive images as attachment. I can recieve the images but image not displayed.

Comment: your question is still not clear, post your code and explain. update question

Answer (score 0):

try `image/*` instead of `"image/png"`